# How to access the content of an iframe with no name and id through JQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

The iframe is something like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.another-domain.com/whatever.php">
<html>
<head>Header</head>
<body>

<div div="mydiv">text</div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I want to access #mydiv from the parent window. The iframe contents are from another domain.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... from a *totally* different domain? If so, then I'm afraid you won't be able to do this. That's called "cross-site-scripting" and browsers don't allow that to happen.

However, if you are parent-page is `parent.domain.com` and your child is on `child.domain.com`, then you can access the contents of the iframe using the `window` object:

`child_frame = document.getElementById('myFrameId');`
`inner_div = child_frame.document.getElementById('mydiv');`
`/* now do stuff with inner div */`

I'm pulling that off the top of my head: YMMV!

Comment: You'd want child_frame = $('iframe'), since he specified that the iframe has no id.

Answer (score 1):

If its cross-domain id ont think youll be able to do it. Iframes are subject to the same "same domain" policies as ajax i believe.